# CSS: small colorful box over corner of a big parent box

Tags: css, angular, primeng

Please refer screenshot below taken from demo app.
[box over box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSMlo.png)
I need to create a colorful small square box appearing on left corner but as if over the big parent square box(including the contents inside of the white/parent box).

request you to please let me know if you have any suggestions
the application will be an Angular-8 with Prime icons used widely.
thanks

Update: component structure looks is as follow, see attachment:
[component structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgY3k.png)

Comment: Please share your component code structure?

Comment: @HirenDavda updated the question with said component structure. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set green color box using css like position absolute and top css properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the `:after` pseudo-class. See the snippet for a demo.

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.element {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.element:after {
  content: " ";
  background: #00ee00;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="element">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  
  <p class="text">Text text text</p>
  <p class="text">Text text text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @Shai. this does answer my question completely. however, i forgot to mention that the colorful small box(green one in this case) could be a dynamic one with different color and shape. it could be a triagle or circle based on condition. i tried to create an "element2" just before "element" with giving these ".element:after" but it was not same as the code you mentioned. is there a way to achieve this without ".element:after" class but with an actual html element with said class. the elements will be displayed/hidded based on condition. thanks in advance

Comment: I think i found the mistake in my code. "element2" inside "element" will work same as ".element:after" with css properties and values remaining same. let me try that. thanks a lot for your help. will mark the answer as soon as i am able to get close to the desired design. :)

Comment: Yes, you can do it exactly the same as I did but with a child element, using the same CSS code I placed in the `:after` CSS selector. Just drop the `content: " "` rule :)